# Multithread for loop function not working correctly

Tags: c++, multithreading

I tried to implement simple for loop running on custom number of threads like this:

```
#include <thread>

template<typename func, typename... args>
void threadFor(int numOfThreads, int repeats, func f, args... a)
{
    auto forPart = [&](int repeats){
        for (int i = 0; i < repeats; ++i) f(i, a...);
    };
    
    int part      = repeats / numOfThreads;
    int remainder = repeats % numOfThreads;

    std::thread threads[numOfThreads];

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; ++i)
    {
        threads[i] = std::thread(forPart,part + (i < remainder));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; ++i) threads[i].join();
}
```

I am testing it in the following way:

```
#include <iostream>

void increment(int i, int* j){++*j;}

int main()
{
    int j = 0;
    threadFor(8,1000000, increment, &j);

    std::cout << j;
}
```

When I execute the code, j is less than 1,000,000. Also, the code sometimes crushes because of double deletion or segmentation error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Edit] your question to quote that error and identify where it came from, please. And if your code crashes, then you can use a debugger to trap those errors and figure out their source.

Comment: `std::thread threads[numOfThreads];` is not valid c++. Use a `vector` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to synchronize your threads' access to the shared variable.

std::atomic?

This gets 1,000,000:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

template<typename func, typename... args>
void threadFor(int numOfThreads, int repeats, func f, args... a)
{
  auto forPart = [&](int repeats) {
    for (int i = 0; i < repeats; ++i) f(i, a...);
  };

  int part = repeats / numOfThreads;
  int remainder = repeats % numOfThreads;

  std::vector<std::thread> threads;// [numOfThreads];
  threads.reserve(numOfThreads);

  for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; ++i)
  {
    threads.push_back(std::thread(forPart, part + (i < remainder)));
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; ++i) threads[i].join();
}


void increment(int i, std::atomic<int>* j) { ++*j; }

int main()
{
  std::atomic<int> j = 0;
  threadFor(8, 1000000, increment, &j);

  std::cout << j;
}
```

Comment: Why is it better to use vector than c-style array?

Comment: @MartinVítVavřík - C++ standard doesn't allow arrays with non-compile-time-const dimension. [ADDED] see cigien's comment to your question

Answer (score 1):

Your `increment` function never actually modifies the `j` argument:

```
void increment(int i, int* j) { 
    *j++; 
}
```

In this definition, you increment `j` (which is a copy of the original pointer) to an invalid location, and dereference it, invoking undefined behavior.

Instead, you need to do:

```
void increment(int i, int* j) { 
    ++*j;
}
```

which dereferences `j`, giving an l-value that is incremented.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem to be the only error, in my debug script I have rewritten it as `*j += 1` (and know also as `(*j) += 0`) and I am still getting double free error.